# Mocking the HTTP backend in JavaScript protractor end to end testing

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, protractor, e2e-testing

I have some end to end test (JavaScript + Protractor) and I need to mock an API backend.

I'm using http-backend-proxy:

That's what I did:

```
var HttpBackend = require('http-backend-proxy');
var myData = require('myFakeApiResponse.json');

this.proxy = new HttpBackend(browser);  
this.proxy.whenGET(/.+\/api\/groups\/.+/).respond(200, myData);
```

JavaScript complains that whenGET is not a function.

If I do like this:

```
this.proxy.whenGET(/.+\/api\/groups\/.+/);
```

It doesn't complain anymore (but obviously I need to set the response so I need the `.respond()` part)

I can't understand why it doesn't work. The proxy object seems to be set, when I console.log it I get:

```
{ when: [Function],
  whenGET: [Function],
  whenPUT: [Function],
  whenHEAD: [Function],
  whenPOST: [Function],
  whenDELETE: [Function],
  whenPATCH: [Function],
  whenJSONP: [Function],
  context: {},
  flush: [Function],
  syncContext: [Function],
  onLoad: [Getter] }
```

it seems to be a proper JavaScript object (even the whenGET() function is listed!)

Comment: Have you added `angular-mocks.js` to your page HTML?

Comment: Can you provide the actual stack trace, if any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also using http-backend-proxy.

I need this for pass throughs (mostly html pages as its an Angular app):

```
proxy.onLoad.whenGET(/.*/).passThrough();
```

and also onLoad:

```
proxy.onLoad.whenGET('the url').respond(...);
```

When I navigate using browser.get(...), the onLoad.whenGET gets invoked.